# converting time series to numeric series, but obtain time "distance" relationship in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have columns with dates and values in this form:

```
                      time  value
0  2020-07-01 12:50:48.786  0.978
1  2020-07-01 12:51:02.132  0.984
2  2020-07-01 12:51:02.162  0.984
3  2020-07-01 12:51:02.188  0.984
4  2020-07-01 12:51:02.208  0.984
```

I would like to plot time vs. value, but I would not like to obtain time values in my chart, instead, I would like to have numerical representation on my X-axis. Of course, I can not just change DateTime with range numerical representation, because graph would lose dependency, instead, I am looking for a difference in a millisecond, where I could use the cumulative function to get x-axis as such (example):

```
x = np.array([0,112,234,400 etc..])
```

Is there any inbuild solution for this in pandas, or I would have to write my own function? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does calculating milliseconds meet the intent of your question?

```
df['time']  = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] )
df['shift'] = df['time'].shift()
df['diff'] = df['time'] - df['shift']
    time    value   shift   diff
0   2020-07-01 12:50:48.786 0.978   NaT NaT
1   2020-07-01 12:51:02.132 0.984   2020-07-01 12:50:48.786 00:00:13.346000
2   2020-07-01 12:51:02.162 0.984   2020-07-01 12:51:02.132 00:00:00.030000
3   2020-07-01 12:51:02.188 0.984   2020-07-01 12:51:02.162 00:00:00.026000
4   2020-07-01 12:51:02.208 0.984   2020-07-01 12:51:02.188 00:00:00.020000
```